# How to implement in upstart that a service is preventive restarted every x hours?

Tags: cron, upstart

I have a component --- started with upstart --- with a bug. The bug causes the application to freeze and unfortunately, it does not crush.

As a temporary walk-around, I want to force the service to restart every x hours, before the bug freezes the application. Is it possible with the upstart?

I could implement a cron job for it but I would prefer to keep it in upstart to have all start logic in one place.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect you to do this with a "reload" or "restart" option from -outside- the script. See mysql and apache as an example: "service apache restart".

Alter your upstart script so it has a "restart" feature and then add that as a command to "/etc/crontab".

And yes, I understand this is not your intended answer but I also expect that the upstart script does NOT restart itself if it freezes and there is no crash. An "oncrash" can trigger a restarte but an "onfreeze" is probably not detectable.

---

See [chapter 16 Daemon behaviour](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#daemon-behaviour) for some tips on this.